# CreatingDC not updating after Domain controller Migration

Tags: sql-server-2014, availability-groups, clustering, active-directory, domain

Recently we have switched our domain controller and during the migration I have noticed on the cluster manager the below error

Cluster network name resource 'Cluster Name' encountered an error enabling the network name on this node. The reason for the failure was: 'Check if a domain controller is reachable and that the computer object is present in Active Directory'.

In our environment we have always on availability group. I am able to move resources but did not try to failover . 
When I looked into the registry settings HKEY_LOCAL-MACHINE - Cluster - Resources I have noticed the CREATINGDC still showing the old Domain controller. Please advise whether I need to update it to the new domain controller or I can leave as is.  Any help will be greatly appreciated  as I fear failover will not work.

Comment: Sounds like permissions might not have survived your migration intact. Permissions are included [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/create-or-configure-an-availability-group-listener-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#Restrictions)

Comment: Will appreciate if you can elaborate a little please